# Combine 2 map columns in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hello I am using the combine udf from brickhouse to combine to maps for the below example

select combine(map('a',1,'b',0),map('a',0,'c',1))

If does combine the maps but I want to keep the highest value while combining the maps. is the possible?

Comment: If [this](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/brickhouse/udf/collect/CombineUDF.java) is your combine UDF, I see no functionality that you seek. You would have to take their UDF and enhance it with your logic.

Comment: hi, can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `udf` to concat the `map to get the key having max value` as below-

```scala
       val mapConcat = udf((map1: Map[String, Int], map2: Map[String, Int]) => {

      val finalMap = mutable.Map.empty[String, mutable.ArrayBuffer[Int]]
      map1.foreach { case (key: String, value: Int) =>
        if (finalMap.contains(key))
          finalMap(key) :+ key
        else finalMap.put(key, mutable.ArrayBuffer(value))
      }
      map2.foreach { case (key: String, value: Int) =>
        if (finalMap.contains(key))
          finalMap(key) :+ key
        else finalMap.put(key, mutable.ArrayBuffer(value))
      }
      finalMap.mapValues(_.max)
    })
    spark.udf.register("my_map_concat", mapConcat)
    spark.range(2).selectExpr("map('a',1,'b',0)","map('a',0,'c',1)",
      "my_map_concat(map('a',1,'b',0),map('a',0,'c',1))")
      .show(false)
```

Output-

```
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
|map(a, 1, b, 0) |map(a, 0, c, 1) |UDF(map(a, 1, b, 0), map(a, 0, c, 1))|
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 0]|[a -> 0, c -> 1]|[b -> 0, a -> 1, c -> 1]             |
|[a -> 1, b -> 0]|[a -> 0, c -> 1]|[b -> 0, a -> 1, c -> 1]             |
+----------------+----------------+-------------------------------------+
```